# c print tree containing struct

Tags: c, printing, struct, tree

I am trying to write a binary tree program where the nodes of the tree contain a struct of 'inventory'.
The program is supposed to read from a txt file and insert the information into a tree (sorted by part number).

The problem I am encountering is that I cannot figure out why the print_inorder function is making my program crash.

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>



typedef struct inventory
{
    char invName[36];
    int  invPartNo;
    int  invQOH;
    float invUnitCost;
    float invPrice;
}stock;

typedef struct btree {
    void *data;
    int key_value;
    struct btree *left;
    struct btree *right;
} tree_t;

//function definitions
struct btree *initTree();
void print_inventory(struct inventory *stuff);
void print_inorder(tree_t *tree);
struct inventory * ReadData(FILE *fptr);
struct btree *search(int key, struct btree *leaf);
struct btree *insert(struct btree *root, int x);
void readFromTxt(FILE *fp, struct btree *head);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //currently in initTree, the first node is empty (doesn't contain an inventory item) and has key_value 1
    //need to set key_value to equal product code

    struct btree *root;
    root = initTree();
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    readFromTxt(fp, root);
    print_inorder(root);

    return 0;
}

//initialize tree
struct btree *initTree()
{
    struct btree *temp = (struct btree*)malloc(sizeof btree);
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->key_value = 1;
    return temp;
}

//print inventory
void print_inventory(struct inventory *stuff)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", stuff->invName);
    printf("Part Number: %.5d\n", stuff->invPartNo);//printf(“ %.9d”, x)
    printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", stuff->invQOH);
    printf("Unit Cost: %0.2f\n", stuff->invUnitCost);
    printf("Price %0.2f\n\n", stuff->invPrice);
}

//recursively print tree
void print_inorder(tree_t *tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL) { //problem likely here
        print_inorder(tree->left);

        //printf("%d\n", tree->data);
        //printf inventory values
        if(tree->key_value != 1) //don''t print root
            print_inventory((struct inventory *)tree->data);

        print_inorder(tree->right);
    }
}

//read user input to produce new leaf with inventory struct
struct inventory * ReadData(FILE *fptr)
{
    struct inventory *temp = (struct inventory *)malloc(sizeof inventory);

    if(fptr==stdin)
        printf("Enter item name: ");
    fscanf_s(fptr, "%s", temp->invName);
    if(fptr==stdin)
        printf("Enter item part number: ");
    fscanf_s(fptr, "%d", &temp->invPartNo);
    if(fptr==stdin)
        printf("Enter item quantity on hand: ");
    fscanf_s(fptr, "%d", &temp->invQOH);
    if(fptr==stdin)
        printf("Enter item unit cost: ");
    fscanf_s(fptr, "%f", &temp->invUnitCost);
    if(fptr==stdin)
        printf("Enter item price: ");
    fscanf_s(fptr, "%f", &temp->invPrice);

    return temp;
}

//search tree
struct btree *search(int key, struct btree *leaf)
{
    if(leaf != 0)
    {
        if(key == leaf->key_value)
            return leaf;

        else if(key < leaf->key_value)
            return search(key, leaf->left);

        else
            return search(key, leaf->right);
    }
}

//add to tree
struct btree *insert(struct btree *root, int x)
{
 if(!root)
  {
    root=(struct btree*)malloc(sizeof(struct btree));
    root->key_value = x;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    return(root);
  }
  if(root->key_value > x)
     root->left = insert(root->left,x);
  else
   {
     if(root->key_value < x)
    root->right = insert(root->right,x);
   }
   return(root);
 }


void readFromTxt(FILE *fp, struct btree *head)
{
    if( fp != NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            struct btree *tNode = (struct btree*)malloc(sizeof btree);
            struct inventory *newNode =  (struct inventory*)malloc(sizeof inventory);
            fgets(newNode->invName, 100, fp);
            fscanf(fp, " %d %d %f %f ", &newNode->invPartNo,&newNode->invQOH,&newNode->invUnitCost,&newNode->invPrice);
            tNode->data = newNode;
            tNode->key_value = newNode->invPartNo;
            head->key_value++;
            insert( head, tNode->key_value );
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the txt file I am trying to read from:

```
1/4 drive socket set
19343
6
38.55
43.25
Claw Hammer
13448
14
3.27
4.89
#2 Flat Blade Screwdriver
12488
24
.70
1.85
#2 Phillips Screwdriver
12455
17
0.81
2.00
#1 Phillips Screwdriver
12456
27
0.67
1.80
#1 Flat Blade Screwdriver
12489
36
.65
1.75
```

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` : bad. EOF is in the input(`fscanf(fp,...`).

Comment: `fscanf_s(fptr, "%s", temp->invName);` : needs buffer size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many design flaws in your code.

- You keep a dummy node as root (or head) with a special key of 1. But later, you increment the head's key to keep track of the item count. Finally, you check for the special key of 1 when printing the iventory data. Because the key is no longer 1 and the inventory data of your dummy head node is `NULL`, you access illegal memory - seg fault!
- When you insert new nodes, you don't actually pass the node, just the key value. Then you create a new node on the spot with that id and *without* the inventory data. In fact, the `data` pointer is uninitialised and not even guaranteed to be `NULL`.
- I know that the dummy node means that you never have to update the head, but that's not a good design. Instead you should start with a `NULL` head and update it when you insert new nodes. This is usually done by passing a pointer to a pointer to the nodes.
- Please keep your naming consistent. You should not call a new piece of inventory data `newNode` when you have a new node (called `tNode`) right next to it. Also, what are the `typedefs` for? You only use `tree_t` once. Better stuck with `struct btree`.
- The way you read in your data is also error prone. For example, you read a buffer of at most 100 chars to `newNode->invName`, which can hold only 36 chars. Recipe for disaster. Mixing `fscanf` and `fgets` is usually not such as good idea and please don't use `feof` - check the return values of the other `f` functions to see whether you have reached the end of the file.
- Memory in C is not garbage-collected. That means for every `malloc` there should be an according `free`. Go easy on the allocation - you allocate too much, actually - and try to clean up the tree after you have used it.